# Replace char inside character array

Tags: c

The following code aborts with a segmentation fault error at the commented line. The line is intended to do a simple replacement of one character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int num(char zf[], int n) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // assignment = seg fault
        if (zf[i] == ',') zf[i] = '.';

        if (!isdigit(zf[i]) && zf[i] != '+' && zf[i] != '-' && zf[i] != '.') {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}

int main(void) {
    if (num("-3+3,0", 6)) {
        printf("valid\n");
    } else {
        printf("not valid\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm looking for an explenation why there's an error and what the solution is to this? strncpy? The parameters and datatypes of the function num are not to be changed.

Comment: Modifying a string literal is undefined behaviour. Here's a question with a similar problem (and there are many more): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943312/segmentation-fault-char-pointer?rq=1

Comment: it is [undefined behavior to modify a string literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372952/modifying-a-char-const-string)

Comment: Yep, string literals are constants.

Comment: Funny, this is a mock exam and "num(char zf[], int n)" is provided by the teacher. Not sure how to solve this at all.

Comment: @thpetrus, Don't give it a string literal. Give it something it can actually modify.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour, Hmm, interesting. I've always had the notion that if the other question can answer this one, it should be a dupe, even if the two questions are not the same. The way I see it, having a good answer there that answers the current question definitely helps, and then any new answer that comes up basically repeats that one. Still, considering I participated in that question, it would be nice to get notification that it has a meta post. I never know what's going on in meta.

Comment: @chris I was pinged which is how I knew but I agree a notification would be nice. The question was reopened so I answered before someone else could make another hash of it.

Comment: The literal: "-3+3,0" will be in the .const section of the link.  That is a nonwritable section.

Answer (score 6):

String literals are compiled into the program and stored somewhere in the binary as an array of bytes. You can try the `strings` command in Linux to find string literals in a binary.

The string constants most likely exist in read only parts of programs and that is why it was made undefined behavior to modify them. A segmentation fault happens when you try to access or modify parts of memory that should not be accessed or modified.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: I changed the text a little.

Answer (score 1):

Though in C string literals have type of non-constant character arrays nevertheless the C Standard does not allow to change them.

> 4 The same considerations apply to each element of the sequence in a
>   string literal as if it were in an **integer character constant**

If a program attempts to modify a string literal then its **behaviour is undefined**.

You should defined main the following way

```
int main(void) {
    char s[] = "-3+3,0";

    if (num(s, sizeof( s ) - 1 )) {
        printf("valid\n");
    } else {
        printf("not valid\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here in `if (num("-3+3,0", 6))` ,  **"-3+3,0"** is stored in read-only memory.  So modifiying it, will result in segmentation fault.

Use an array so that   `"-3+3,0"` is stored in stack. Then we can modify the values.