# Modifying value of char pointer in c produces segfault

Tags: c, pointers, char, dereference

The following code produces a segmentation fault on my system. I can't figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    char * a = "abc";
    *a = 'c';
    printf("%c\n", *a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't believe that it is the earliest one, but there is a duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/943191/2509

Answer (score 6):

The standard explicitly lists this as undefined behavior in §J.2:

> — The program attempts to modify a
>   string literal (6.4.5)

If you want to copy it into a local array, do:

```
char a[] = "abc";
```

`a` is an array on the stack, and you can modify it freely.

Answer (score 2):

Attempting to modify a string literal causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Is there any way in c to modify string literals then? There has to be.

Comment: @Smoke, no there is not.  You need to copy the literal into an array that's not in read-only memory.