# Uppercase in C language

Tags: c, uppercase

I have this code:

```
void changeToCapital(char* str)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<strlen(str); i++) 
    {
        str[i] =str[i] -32;
    }
}
```

and this method is supposed to get a `char*` variable, and change it to its uppercase.  For some reason I'm getting an error saying `EXECUTE_BAD_ACCESS`.

The calling function:

```
char* s = "itzik";
changeToCapital(s);
printf("%s\n",s);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you trying to modify a string literal?

Comment: Sounds like pointer issues - what's the string pointed to by `str` when it crashes?

Comment: im doing str[i], isnt that a char?

Comment: Your function takes a `char *` though. You need to pass it `&str[i]`

Comment: @MikeKwan nope, the implementation is good (well, it could be good if it was well-implemented...). The issue is that he's modifying a string literal.

Comment: @H2CO3: I was just commenting based off of him saying he is passing in a `str[i]`. The code was only added afterwards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modifying value of char pointer in c produces segfault](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189782/modifying-value-of-char-pointer-in-c-produces-segfault)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is most likely because you are passing it a pointer to non-writable memory, such as one obtained from a string literal:

```
char *ptr = "Hello";
changeToCapital(ptr); // <<== ERROR !
```

You can change the call to avoid the error:

```
char ptr[] = "Hello";
changeToCapital(ptr);
```

On a side note, your change to upper case works only when all letters are in the lower case. You should use `toupper(ch)` function instead of subtracting 32.

```
void changeToCapital(char* str) {
    for (; *str = toupper(*str) ; str++)
        ;
}
```

Comment: and `toupper(ch)` still won't work for [Turkish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_alphabet#Distinctive_features)

Comment: @Robert Cooper - Who gives a hoot about Turkish !!

Comment: @RobertCooper I think not working for Turkish (and a whole lot of other languages) is still better than not working even for English :)

Answer (score 4):

First:

You are constantly calculating `strlen`. Instead, you should store the length of the string in a local variable.

Second: you are probably calling the function like this:

```
char *str = "Hello World";
changeToCapital(str);
```

This is **BAD**. `"Hello World"` is `const`, and cannot be modified by your program. Instead, you should specify your string as a character array, to ensure that it is immutable:

```
char str[] = "Hello World";
changeToCapital(str);
```

Comment: The value of `strlen(str)` is not constant in his code. Consider the effect of  `str[i] =str[i] -32;` when `str[i] == ' '`.

Comment: @Robᵩ that's just a bad design not to check for unexpected results (and thus handle any special characters as lowercase letters).

Comment: @H2CO3 - without question OP's program is wrong on many levels. I'm merely observing that Richard's optimization will not produce identical results.

Comment: Of course, because Richard's fix makes the function work at least for some cases, instead of always causing an error.