# Capitalizing a string in C

Tags: c, eclipse

[image]

The program was supposed to take a string dynamically from a user then capitalize it, but when I run it after I type in the string nothing seems to be happening.

Comment: Please post code along with the question .

Comment: Please don't post images of text, especially not code. Copy-paste the actual text into the body of the question instead. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uppercase in C language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689876/uppercase-in-c-language)

Comment: Your program has no instructions to print anything other than the prompt "string please:". OK, it is quite natural not to see anything to be happening because humans typically cannot see what is going in computers easily. Do you have any *questions*?

Comment: Maybe you should print out the new string?

Comment: Post relevant code/information here.

Comment: okay , sorry guys about the image

Comment: and thanks I solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to capitalize a C string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main() {
    int i = 0;
    char str[] = "foobar";
    while(str[i]) {
        putchar (toupper(str[i]));
        i++;
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Test it [online](http://ideone.com/VQdpVo).