# c++ segfault: char pointers

Tags: c++, c, pointers, char, segmentation-fault

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you reverse a string in place in C or C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198199/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-c-or-c)
>   [Why is this C code causing a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614723/why-is-this-c-code-causing-a-segmentation-fault)
>   [Modifying value of char pointer in c produces segfault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189782/modifying-value-of-char-pointer-in-c-produces-segfault)

Running a very simple code example

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

char* last_char(char* s){
  char* last = s;
  while (*last) ++last;
  return last;
}

char* in_place_reverse(char* s) {
  char* left = s;
  char* right = last_char(s);
  char temp;

  while( left < right ) {
    temp = *left;
    *left = *right;
    *right = temp;

    left++;
    right--;
  }

  return s;
}

int main(){
  char * s = "letters\n";
  std::cout << in_place_reverse(s);
}
```

All the time I get

```
 Segmentation fault
```

But from my point of view I'm not doing anything illegal within the code.
Please help me to determine what's wrong.

P.S. I compile with

```
g++ example.c
```

Comment: You should run this code in the debugger.  It will tell you which line caused the seg-fault, and you should be able to work backwards from there.

Comment: Note that your function last_char returns the delimiting `\0`, so if your code will not segfault, then `std::cout` will output nothing because your first char in the string will be `\0` after reversion.

Comment: [This code to reverse a string is really short](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6560310/176769).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You are trying to modify a string literal.  This may work, it may not, or it may crash.  This is invoking *undefined behavior*.  Use `char s[] = "letters\n"` to make a mutable copy.
2. `last_char()` in fact returns a pointer to the sentinel `'\0'` at the end of the string -- it points beyond the last character.  Change `return last` to `return last - 1`.  Otherwise you are going to move the sentinel around too, and that's almost certainly not what you want.  (Note that this will return a pointer to garbage if the string is zero-length.  You should fast-succeed in `in_place_reverse()` if `*s == '\0'` to avoid this complexity.)

Comment: are you sure about #2?
i've tested it separately and it always returns last character.
it would return '\0' if the cycle was `while (*last++);`

Comment: Yes.  `last_char()` will return `last` only when `!*last`.

Answer (score 2):

You are modifying a string literal and string literals are non-modifiable.

Use `char s[] = "letters\n";` instead