# Why can't I write to a string literal while I *can* write to a string object?

Tags: c++, string, stl

If i define something like below,

```
char  *s1 = "Hello";
```

why I can't do something like below,

```
*s1 = 'w'; // gives segmentation fault ...why???
```

What if I do something like below,

```
string s1 = "hello";
```

Can I do something like below,

```
*s1 = 'w';
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is this C code causing a segmentation fault?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614723/why-is-this-c-code-causing-a-segmentation-fault)

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943191

Comment: Not a duplicate because those questions just ask the first part and don't ask for the difference to the C++ string case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `"Hello"` creates a const char[]. This decays to a `const char*` not a `char*`. In C++ string literals are read-only. You've created a pointer to such a literal and are trying to write to it.

But when you do

```
string s1 = "hello";
```

You copy the const char* "hello" into `s1`. The difference being in the first example `s1` **points to** read-only "hello" and in the second example read-only "hello" is **copied into** non-const `s1`, allowing you to access the elements in the copied string to do what you wish with them.

If you want to do the same with a char* you need to allocate space for char data and copy hello into it

```
char hello[] = "hello"; // creates a char array big enough to hold "hello"
hello[0] = 'w';           //  writes to the 0th char in the array
```

Comment: Just for the correctness: the type of "hello" isn't char const* (or const char* if you insist) but char const[6] which decays at its first chance to char const* (or, accepts being assigned to char*).

Answer (score 2):

string literals are usually allocated in read-only data segment.

Comment: True but it's more helpful to restrain conversation to the scope of the abstract machine that C++ defines. It already goes out of its way to ensure that string literals are treated as constant data; there is no need to talk about physical realities that make this a useful/safe choice, especially as those realities can vary in factual accuracy across the wide range of physical implementations in use around the world and through time.

Answer (score 1):

Because `Hello` resides in read only memory.  Your signature should actually be

```
const char* s1 = "Hello";
```

If you want a mutable buffer then declare `s1` as a `char[]`.  `std::string` overloads `operator []`, so you can index into it, i.e., `s1[index] = 'w'`.

Answer (score 1):

Time to confuse matters:

```
char s0[] = "Hello";
s0[0] = 'w';
```

This is perfectly valid! Of course, this doesn't answer the original question so here we go: string literals are created in read-only memory. That is, their type is `char const[n]` where `n` is the size of the string (including the terminating null character, i.e. `n == 6` for the string literal `"Hello"`. But why, oh, why can this type be used to initialize a `char const*`? The answer is simply backward compatibility, respectively compatibility to [old] C code: by the time `const` made it into the language, lots of places already initialized `char*` with string literals. Any decent compiler should warn about this abuse, however.