# How to work with wchar_t strings?

Tags: c++, wchar-t

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C++, Why can't I write to a string literal while I *can* write to a string object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718740/in-c-why-cant-i-write-to-a-string-literal-while-i-can-write-to-a-string-ob)

I'm having my first experience with wchar_t strings and I'm having a lot of trouble. Each time I try to access a character in an wchar_t* the program crashes with segmentation fault. How should I do if I want to replace one character in the string with another? But when deleting a character from the end of the string?

```
wchar_t * my_string[] = L"Hello";
my_string[0] = L'Y'; // Should be "Yello". Instead, gives segmentation fault
```

[edit]
Doesn't matter, I've just made a fool out of myself. I'll check elsewhere on the internet. It's my fault, I shouldn't be bothering you with such silly questions...

Comment: Without example code, this question is worse than useless.

Comment: That code isn't even legal.  The type of `my_string[1]` is `wchar_t*`, you can't assign a character value to a pointer variable.  You also don't seem to understand zero-based indexing.

Comment: Fine then I should revise my C knowledge unless I want to make a fool out of myself. I knew about zero-based indexing but I'm used to working with other types of arrays from index 1. I just rushed and made a typo above. And this is true, I don't have much programming experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't supply much information, but, since you talk about segmentation fault, the most common errors derived from the fact that memory management functions usually works on bytes while `wchar_t` has a size greater than 1.

When doing pointer arithmetic over char, the `sizeof(char)` is almost never taken in count, since it is 1 by definition. But `wchar_t` is wider, hence where bytes length are required, a multiplication of `sizeof(wchar_t)` must be placed.

[EDIT] Sorry but the sample has nothing to do with `wchar_t` itself:

`wchat_t* my_string[]` is an arry of wchar_t-pointers, the first of which is made to point to "Hello", and the other are left uninitialized.  Just remove the *.

Comment: I've just added example code above... thanks for kind answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I seem to just be making a fool out of myself, showing off my poor experience. But what if I have a function which has wchar_t * (a wide char string) as one of its parameters and I want to make a change in it?

Comment: @PetruDimitriu wchar_t* are not semantically different from char* or from int*. If it points to 10 wchar_t and you want to change the 7th, just do ptr[6] = L'.';

The problem is that if ptr point to a literal (a string constant), you cannot change it since it is stored as read-only.