# Why tolower() affecting other string?

Tags: c

Why output of this program is always:

```
example 

example
```

If i change first line with second in for loop, then output will look like this:

```
EXAMPLE

EXAMPLE
```

What i am doing wrong?

```
string key = "EXAmple";
string ukey = key; 
string lkey = key;

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(key); i++)
{
  ukey[i] = toupper(key[i]); 
  lkey[i] = tolower(key[i]);
}       

printf("%s\n", ukey);
printf("%s\n", lkey);
```

Comment: AFAIK, `string` is not a defined term in C.  Thus, the answer would depend on how it was defined.

Comment: Post the definition of `string`.  Is it `char *`?

Comment: Is there a `typedef char* string;` somewhere? Or worse, `#define string char*`? It might be in a header file you `#include`.

Comment: I have `#include <string.h>` in header. I am noob programmer and i dont know how to answer your questions

Answer (score 5):

The definition of `string` is likely to be `char*`. Consequently, `key`, `ukey` and `lkey` are actually pointers pointing to exactly the same memory; they are just aliases for the same thing.

Comment: Isn't writing to a string literal undefined behavior?

Comment: Might be; I don't know.

Comment: @ScottHunter: Yes, but that doesn't preclude it appearing to work just fine.

Comment: This answer linked below is good: it might work but causes undefined behaviour, especially if another string shares the same literal. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245664/string-literals-in-c

Comment: The answer seems to be complicated; the discussion here is related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718740/in-c-why-cant-i-write-to-a-string-literal-while-i-can-write-to-a-string-ob

Answer (score 2):

Here, `ukey` and `lkey` are likely both pointers to the same array in memory.  In C, an array reference is just a pointer to the first item in the array, and using the [] operator just returns the values at each position of the array (dereferenced).

So, ukey and lkey both refer to the exact same characters.

Sounds like you want to use `strcpy()` instead of ordinary assignment, or the equivalent for your custom type `string`.

Or use C++ and its string type.

Comment: That would depend on the definition of `string`, no?

Comment: True.  I am making an assumption about that, I suppose.  Fixed.